# Why is my screen blank in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I opened up an A-Frame scene both using the Hello World Codepen and the boilerplate, but I just get a blank white screen in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser).It works for me.

Details below:

Chrome

First, enable hardware acceleration:

Go to chrome://settings
Click the + Show advanced settings button
In the System section, ensure the Use hardware acceleration when available checkbox is checked (you'll need to relaunch Chrome for any changes to take effect)
Then enable WebGL:

Go to chrome://flags
Ensure that Disable WebGL is not activated (you'll need to relaunch Chrome for any changes to take effect)
Then inspect the status of WebGL:

Go to chrome://gpu
Inspect the WebGL item in the Graphics Feature Status list. The status will be one of the following:
Hardware accelerated — WebGL is enabled and hardware-accelerated (running on the graphics card).
Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable — WebGL is enabled, but running in software. See here for more info: "For software rendering of WebGL, Chrome uses SwiftShader, a software GL rasterizer."
Unavailable — WebGL is not available in hardware or software.
If the status is not "Hardware accelerated", then the Problems Detected list (below the the Graphics Feature Status list) may explain why hardware acceleration is unavailable.

If your graphics card/drivers are blacklisted, you can override the blacklist. Warning: this is not recommended! (see blacklists note below). To override the blacklist:

Go to chrome://flags
Activate the Override software rendering list setting (you'll need to relaunch Chrome for any changes to take effect)
For more information, see: Chrome Help: WebGL and 3D graphics.

Firefox

First, enable WebGL:

Go to about:config
Search for webgl.disabled
Ensure that its value is false (any changes take effect immediately without relaunching Firefox)
Then inspect the status of WebGL:

Go to about:support
Inspect the WebGL Renderer row in the Graphics table:
If the status contains a graphics card manufacturer, model and driver (eg: "NVIDIA Corporation -- NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M OpenGL Engine"), then WebGL is enabled.
If the status is something like "Blocked for your graphics card because of unresolved driver issues" or "Blocked for your graphics driver version", then your graphics card/driver is blacklisted.
If your graphics card/drivers are blacklisted, you can override the blacklist. Warning: this is not recommended! (see blacklists note below). To override the blacklist:

Go to about:config
Search for webgl.force-enabled
Set it to true
(Like Chrome, Firefox has a Use hardware acceleration when available checkbox, in Preferences > Advanced > General > Browsing. However, unlike Chrome, Firefox does not require this checkbox to be checked for WebGL to work.)

Safari

Go to Safari's Preferences
Select the Advanced tab
Ensure that the Show Develop menu in menu bar checkbox is checked
In Safari's Develop menu, ensure that Enable WebGL is checked

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if WebGL and hardware acceleration is enabled in your browser and check that your GPU is not on your system's blacklist.